# How to setup a mobilink client and server and test the synchronisation?

Tags: mobilink

I'm was wondering how to setup and test a mobilink client and server. 
Actually, the system is quite complex and I would like some guidance.

firstly, I have a windows 7 OS, would that suffice or would I need a server edition OS for me to setup.

Secondly, can I have two instances of the same server running on my system?

How should I go about getting the client and server installed and communicate ? 
If anyone could direct me to some links it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run MobiLink clients and servers on the same computer, then Windows 7 should be okay. Note that the MobiLink server connects to a database server (referred to as the consolidated database), such as Oracle, SQL Server, DB2 or a Sybase database. Do you also want to run the consolidated database server on the same computer?

You can run two or more instances of a MobiLink server on a computer, as long as they are configured to listen on different ports (or different NICs).

For basic client and server setup, see the [first tutorial](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/mlstart/ml-sc-tutorial.html).

[Other ways to get help with MobiLink and SQL Anywhere](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/sausinghelp/uh-findoutmore.html)